# When flashing image to raspberry pi overites os

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I am new to Linux and am using a raspberry pi 2 model b, and want to use jasper, apl peice of voice control software I have formatted my SD card, flashed raspbian Jessie on to it. And it loads up fine, but when I flash jasper on to it, and try to boot it up it won't boot it up. I've tried using both raspbian Jessie with pixel and lite and neither work.

Answer (score 0):

If you flashed the softwares to same partition of sdcard, it keeps only the last image.

Its good to keep a single partition in your sdcard. Use can partition tool GParted.

First you need to flash raspbian into sdcard, for that you can use win32diskImager which makes it easy.

Expand the partition by using command "raspi-config"

Then you need to clone jasper from git. Use your raspbian LX terminal or any SSH application to install Jasper.Doesn't need to flash Jasper. For reference, use method 3 of https://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/